# Index (zero based) in sql query in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I don't understand this error in this sql query.

The error is

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero

My code c# in error this is :

```
        sql = @String.Format(" UPDATE `tbl_csv` ");
        sql += String.Format(" SET ");     
        sql += String.Format(" xAAA = 1, ");            
        sql += String.Format(" xBBB = {0},  ");
        sql += String.Format(" xCCC = {1},  ");
        sql += String.Format(" xDDD = {2} ");           
        sql += String.Format(" WHERE Id IN ({3}); ",
            ddlBBB.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            ddlCCC.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            ddlDDD.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            Base64ForUrlDecode(Request.QueryString["sId"].ToString()));
```

But If try this diiferent version of sql query I don't have error and the output of query is correct:

```
        sql = @String.Format(" UPDATE `tbl_csv` ");
        sql += String.Format(" SET ");     
        sql += String.Format(" xAAA = 1, ");            
        sql += String.Format(" xBBB = '" + ddlBBB.SelectedValue.ToString() + "',  ");
        sql += String.Format(" xCCC = '" + ddlCCC.SelectedValue.ToString() + "',  ");
        sql += String.Format(" xDDD = '" +  ddlDDD.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' ");            
        sql += String.Format(" WHERE Id IN (" + Base64ForUrlDecode(Request.QueryString["sId"].ToString()) + "); ",
            ddlBBB.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            ddlCCC.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            ddlDDD.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            Base64ForUrlDecode(Request.QueryString["sId"].ToString()));
```

Output :

```
UPDATE `tbl_csv`
SET xAAA = 1,
 xBBB = 'N',
 xCCC = 'N',
 xDDD = 'N'
WHERE
    Id IN ('2357');
```

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Comment: Parameterised query posts incoming in 5 ... 4 ... 3 ... 2 ... 1 ...

Comment: @DavidPilkington just to make you happy: "OP, please never concatenate input into queries - use parameters" - better now?

Comment: Simple explanation: `String.Format` number placeholder count must be same as total parameters passed to the method, starting from index of 0. Also... you should know how to use parameterized query over string concatenation.

Comment: which line throws that error? all of the `string.Format` calls look wrong, but that isn't the error they would raise...

Comment: @MarcGravell glad that we could get that out of the way hahah

Comment: @DavidPilkington now we need something about using `StringBuilder` instead of repeatedly concatenating strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the correct parameters to each separate `string.format` function.

```
sql += String.Format(" xBBB = {0},", ddlBBB.SelectedValue.ToString());
sql += String.Format(" xCCC = {0},", ddlCCC.SelectedValue.ToString());
sql += String.Format(" xDDD = {0} ", ddlCCC.SelectedValue.ToString());           
sql += String.Format(" WHERE Id IN ({0}); ", Base64ForUrlDecode(Request.QueryString["sId"].ToString()));
```

You cannot just add the parameters to the last function. All functions are resolved on their own and then added to the string.

Also, you should be very careful when adding values from your webpage directly in an sql query. If you intend to execute these queries directly on a database, you should always encode the input.

Comment: **No, he should not encode the input, he should use parameters.** Don't tell people how to do a good implementation of broken design, tell them how to do a good implementation of a good design.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are actually seeing:

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

This is because you haven't supplied any *values* to `string.Format` - i.e.

```
string s = string.Format("add {0} and {1}", "foo", 123);
// s now == "add foo and 123"
```

However! In your case adding the values is *not* a good fix - you should use SQL *parameters*, not concatenation. The *bad* fix would be something like:

```
string sql = string.Format(@"
UPDATE `tbl_csv`
SET    xAAA = 1, xBBB = {0},
       xCCC = {1}, xDDD = {2}
WHERE Id IN ({3});", 
       ddlBBB.SelectedValue.ToString(),
       ddlCCC.SelectedValue.ToString(),
       ddlDDD.SelectedValue.ToString(),
       Base64ForUrlDecode(Request.QueryString["sId"].ToString()));
```

The *good* fix would be something like:

```
const string sql = @"
UPDATE `tbl_csv`
SET    xAAA = 1, xBBB = @xBBB,
       xCCC = @xCCC, xDDD = xDDD
WHERE Id IN (@Id);"
```

adding appropriate ADO.NET parameters to your command, noting that `IN` doesn't usually like parameters unless your database has some kind of "split" function, and that different servers have different ways of expressing parameters - instead of `@foo` it might be `:foo`, or simply `?`, etc.